# wkhtmltopdf black lines in generated PDF

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

[image: Imgur]

This is a PDF generated using wkhtmltopdf and it vertical black lines between. From my analysis, they are caused by the bullet points for list, but they only appear in some pages.

I am generating this PDF directly from a large HTML file.

Is there anyway to rectify this issue?

wkhtmltopdf version: 0.10.0 RC2

Platform: Windows

Tried with other versions and in mac os x also, but these lines appear sometimes in PDFs >10-20 pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic list ul causes the problem. Solution is to provide custom css for the list tags.

Temporary solution for this problem:

Add the argument "--no-pdf-compression" for PDF generation.

But the drawback is that it results in really big PDF files.

Update: it only works sometimes